# Python: Christmas Tree with user input for the base

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to get a christmas tree, where the user can input the number of stars, which should be in the last row. The problem is, I don't get, how to get the height from the number of stars in the last row.

So far, I got the tree with an input from the user for how high the tree should get.

```
eingabe = input("Bitte geben Sie die Höhe des Baumes ein: ")
eingabe = int(eingabe)
eingabe = eingabe + 1 
stern = "*"
for i in range(1, eingabe):
    x = (2 * i - 1) * stern
    print(x.center(100))
```

Comment: How do you calculate the height from the number of stars in the last row without Python?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't get it.
Edit: Oh, maybe I got something there.

Comment: But you know how to calculate the number of stars in the last row from the height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of stars in the last row is:

```
stars = rows * 2 - 1
```

Therefore, the height of the tree, knowing the number of stars in the last row, is:

```
rows = (stars + 1) / 2
```

given that the number of stars must be odd because of the way you're drawing it.